# One of my Facebook App lost

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Today, i met a very strange issue about Facebook App, I found one of my Facebook app was lost suddenly, and some of functionality of my site does not work anymore.

But I never do the delete action for this app, how did that happen?

Where can i find some clues who delete this app? and can we take it back?

And anybody met this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Facebook support issue, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question probably doesn't belong on Stack Overflow as it doesn't involve coding, but here is my opinion anyways.

Either someone used the account and deleted the app, or facebook did but I've never had that happened and I've done some pretty frowned upon things with multiple apps.
As to taking it back their policy is pretty clear on the matter, they won't help.

Comment: Sorry about that, i don't know we must include code in the question. i think StackOverflow is one place to ask questions about technologies. And thank you very much for your response